# Medir uso de memória em c

Tags: c, memória

Oi, tem como eu medir o uso de memoria ram de um programa feito em c? Tem alguma ferramenta específica ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Não tenho conhecimento de nenhuma ferramenta deste porte. O que você pode fazer para amenizar o consumo de RAM é usufruir do uso de ponteiros e alocação dinâmica, isso se o seu problema for tempo de execução ou espaço na memória, respectivamente.

Comment: Cada sistema operacional tem uma ferramenta diferente para fazer isso. Você deve especificar o sistema na pergunta para atrair respostas mais exatas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o `valgrind` com a opção `--leak-check=full`.

O seguinte programa aloca e desaloca, repetidamente, blocos de memória por meio das chamadas de `malloc()` e `free()`:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>


#define TAM_BLOCO    (1024)  
#define QTD_BLOCOS   (1000000)

int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < QTD_BLOCOS; i++ )
    {
        char * p = malloc( TAM_BLOCO * sizeof(char) );
        free(p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc testmem.c -o testmem
```

Testando com `valgrind`:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./testmem
==27153== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27153== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27153== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27153== Command: ./testmem
==27153== 
==27153== 
==27153== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27153==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27153==   total heap usage: 1,000,000 allocs, 1,000,000 frees, 1,024,000,000 bytes allocated
==27153== 
==27153== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27153== 
==27153== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27153== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Segundo a saída do `Valgrind`, houveram `1,000,000` chamadas do `malloc()` e do `free()`, que trabalharam com um total de `1,024,000,000 bytes` de memória total.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado.